# Perguntas fechadas que recebem resposta após o fechamento

Tags: suporte

A pergunta citada abaixo obteve uma resposta 7 minutos após ter sido fechada como duplicata:

> [Qual a forma correta para visualizar a soma de dois campos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178506/28595)

Gostaria de saber se isso é um funcionamento esperado do sistema ou se trata de um bug, pois já ocorreu uma vez comigo de estar com a pergunta aberta, e ao publicar a resposta, o sistema impediu com uma notificação de que havia sido fechada.

Comment: Server side é "enforced" depois de umas 4 horas, vide http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91928/246117 e link no texto para postagem do J. Atwood

Comment: @Bacco e o que é enforced?

Comment: Só é uma restrição imposta pelo servidor depois de 4 horas.

Comment: @Bacco mas ao menos para mim, está bloqueando imediatamente após a pergunta ser fechada, já ocorreu duas vezes conforme a resposta diz, o botao é desativado e surge uma notificação.

Answer (score 5):

É normal. O que impede é algo no cliente web. Então é possível passar por cima disto. Mas o que mais acontece é que a resposta tenha sido dada em mobile cujo cliente não tem essa restrição.

Conforme [comentário do @Bacco](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5694/perguntas-fechadas-que-recebem-resposta-ap%C3%B3s-o-fechamento#comment21681_5694), há um limite de 4 horas para isso, depois até o servidor proíbe uma resposta em pergunta fechada.

O fechamento não impede de fato que tenha respostas, é apenas uma dificuldade colocada.

O que não se espera é que a pessoa use essa "brecha". O ideal em caso assim é tentar reabrir se acha que foi fechada equivocadamente. Seja apenas votando para reabrir, seja trazendo para o meta, seja sinalizando para um moderador. Assim fica mais dentro da normalidade. Assim você demonstra respeito à comunidade, mesmo discordando dela.

Mas não há impedimento no sistema em postar respostas depois da pergunta fechada.

Comment: No mobile da para responder mesmo que esteja fechada? Então para que serve fechar a pergunta? Não fazia ideia dessa brecha.

Comment: Não sei se é bem isso. Se não me engano tem um Grace period pra quem já estava escrevendo no momento do fechamento

Comment: @JorgeB. mostrar que ela tem problemas e por uma dificuldade. Está claro que não é certo responder algo fechado, mas não é proibido. Não sei porque não fizeram o mesmo para mobile.

Comment: @bigown eu aqui não consigo responder a uma pergunta fechada. Não sei se você tem poderes especiais.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu respondi o que o Gabe me falou no mod chat. Eu já estive nessa situação, alguns segundos depois não deixou mais postar. Se tiver um período, é mudança recente, já que faz tempo que isso aconteceu comigo.

Comment: Então provavelmente estou enganado, o Gabe deve saber melhor

Comment: Muito interessante isso. Não fazia a mínima ideia. Mas e se eu quiser fazer um app e usar para responder a perguntas já fechadas o que me acontece?

Comment: @JorgeB. você responde como quiser, o servidor não vai impedir. Tem muita coisa que é restrição só no cliente. Outro exemplo é ver o votos positivos e negativos de uma postagem. Só o cliente impede. É proposital.

Comment: @bfavaretto os detalhes só o Gabe sabe. Ou nem ele, mas pode obter c/ os devs.

Comment: @bigown o servidor proibe depois de 4 horas, mas do lado cliente bloqueia imediatamente. Como diz na resposta linkada do bacco, surge uma notificacao e o botao desativa, exatamente como ocorreu comigo. Claro que se o servidor nao bloqueia antes disso, tem meios de contornar isso, mas prefiro não ficar mexendo com esses "metodos alternativos"