# É possível restaurar resposta dada em pergunta removida?

Tags: debate, suporte, respostas, perguntas-fechadas, contas-usuário

Essa pergunta foi fechada pelo sistema como *spam*, *rude* ou *abusiva* e a conta do autor não mais está presente no sistema:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/514495

Visitando seu [histórico de revisões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/514495/revisions) eu pude constatar que motivo do fechamento foi justo(vide terceira versão) e também não tenho a intenção de discutir aqui o mérito ou qualidade da pergunta.

Pois bem. Dei uma resposta a essa pergunta, resposta essa que consequentemente foi removida junto da pergunta:

[image: Imagem do botão restaurar ativo]

Me surgiram algumas dúvidas:

- Por que o botão de restaurar na minha resposta continua ativo já que a pergunta foi removida por conta de um motivo critico?

  - O que aconteceria se eu o clicasse?
- É possível remover o conteúdo inadequado do histórico de revisões de uma publicação?

  - Caso seja possível remover o conteúdo inadequado haveria algum empecilho em iniciar os tramites de reabertura da publicação já, que a pergunta não está mais associada a algum usuário?

Comment: **A causa da remoção do post não foi a violação do código de conduta no histórico, e sim relacionada com remoção da conta do usuário** (o bold foi só para destacar o que importa de fato). Foi um caso de abuso do sistema, conta feita para contorno de bloqueio. "O que aconteceria se eu o clicasse?" boa pergunta, vale o teste. Sobre o código da pergunta, sequer faz sentido. O sujeito jogou um chute qualquer lá pra alguem consertar pra ele, só isso. Sei que é chato perder tempo com um post para acontecer coisa do tipo, mas fica a dica de por foco em coisa boa para não cair nesse tipo de armadilha.

Comment: @Bacco, me arrisquei a fazer [o teste](https://imgur.com/a/W0cpArL) a resposta foi *Não é possível restaurar respostas de perguntas que foram removidas*

Comment: Pois é, faltou um "if pergunta != removida" pra apresentar a opção de restaurar na resposta, né?

Comment: Pensando melhor, nem deveria ter esse if, simplesmente não deveria aparecer como resposta removida. Podia só "herdar" o fundo da pergunta

Comment: Tem certas validações que são bem fracas no SO, tipo o fato de que é possível [responder uma pergunta fechada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5694/100416) durantes as primeiras horas.

Comment: Como uma resposta não existe sem a pergunta, faz sentido o teste ter falhado. De forma geral, acho que primeiro precisaria restaurar a pergunta, mas num caso como esse, feito por conta irregular, não sei se seria possível (ou mesmo desejável)

Comment: é uma ["feature"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN48M.png) :)

Comment: "*Por que o botão de restaurar na minha resposta continua ativo?*" - Tem muita coisa assim no site. Por exemplo, se eu já atingi o limite de votos diários, as setas de upvote/downvote continuam aparecendo, e só depois que eu clicar é que aparece a mensagem dizendo que eu não posso mais votar. O mesmo vale para votos de fechamento (o link de "Fechar" continua aparecendo, e só depois de clicar é que mostra a mensagem dizendo que já atingi o limite).

Comment: Mas é meio inconsistente, pois se eu entrar deslogado aqui nesta pergunta, só aparecem as opções "Compartilhar" e "Seguir" (sendo que se clicar em "Seguir" aparece uma janela dizendo para eu me logar ou criar uma conta). Ou seja, tem opções que não aparecem quando não se aplicam, e tem outras que aparecem mas você só sabe se vai funcionar ou não depois que clicar. É, talvez seja um *bug* mais geral mesmo, sei lá.